# git. See progressive diffs on a file

Tags: git

I made a change that broke something.

How can I effectively scroll back through the changes to a file in git and see the diffs.

Command line is great.  GUI tool is ok.

Eh?

Comment: This is a tool recomendation question, which is against SO's policy. I'd recommend a cursory google search for [git history tools](https://www.google.com/search?q=git+hostory+tools&oq=git+hostory+tools&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l2.2024j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#q=git+history+tools&spell=1)

Comment: Dammit!  This is an important question about how to use Git.  You're moderation is annoying.  I'm happy to ask the question.  Other people are happy to answer it.  Go away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best tool for exploring history in general is `gitk` (part of the basic git suite). To drill down, perhaps you want `git log --patch yourfilename`.

Comment: Thanks!  If I could pick two right answers, `gitk filename` would be the other.

Answer (score 3):

The command `git blame somefile` will show you which commit introduced the most recent change of a line for all lines in a file.  Sometimes this can provide a different perspective from simply looking at each diff independently.

Answer (score 1):

similar to @vonbrand i suggest gitk. use:

`gitk filename`

for a filtered history only containing commits involving `filename`. `filename` can be the name of a file or folder.

on windows, with tortoisegit, you can right click the file/folder and select "show log" and get a equivalent view.

Comment: Thanks!  If I could pick two right answers, `gitk filename` would be the other.